# How to use websocket with fadecandy server to manipulate ws2812b led strips

Tags: javascript, java, json, led, fadecandy

We need help on how can we use websocket with fadecandy server to map 64 led strips.

This is the mapping in fadecandy server

Server configuration JSON:

```
    {
    "listen": [ null, 7890 ],
    "verbose": true,
    "color": {
        "gamma": 2.5,
        "whitepoint": [ 0.7, 0.7, 0.7 ]
    },
    "devices": [
        {
            "type": "fadecandy",
            "serial": "YSEELLIWMMPNTTUT",
            "map": [
                [ 0, 0, 0, 60 ],
                [ 0, 60, 64, 60 ],
                [ 0, 120, 128, 60 ],
                [ 0, 180, 192, 60 ],
                [ 0, 240, 256, 60 ],
                [ 0, 300, 320, 60 ],
                [ 0, 360, 384, 60 ],
                [ 0, 420, 448, 60 ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "fadecandy",
            "serial": "IMOQHJFLPHOVWJUD",
            "map": [
                [ 0, 480, 0, 60 ],
                [ 0, 540, 64, 60 ],
                [ 0, 600, 128, 60 ],
                [ 0, 660, 192, 60 ],
                [ 0, 720, 256, 60 ],
                [ 0, 780, 320, 60 ],
                [ 0, 840, 384, 60 ],
                [ 0, 900, 448, 60 ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "fadecandy",
            "serial": "KEEODXMCGEVDJHIZ",
            "map": [
                [ 0, 960, 0, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1020, 64, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1080, 128, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1140, 192, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1200, 256, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1260, 320, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1320, 384, 60 ],
                [ 0, 1380, 448, 60 ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can we use the fadecandy server mapping to the websocket?

Answer (score 0):

Fade Candy is very nicely documented and packed with examples and you should start with that.

In terms of controlling a strip of 64 leds from webSockets, play with the [mouse.html example](https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy/blob/master/examples/html/mouse.html). As long as your [FadeCandy server](http://localhost:7890/) is running, you should be able to control 40 of the 64 leds with the mouse example.
You can easily tweak the example, for example `var leds = 40;` will become `var leds = 40;`

The key elements are at the bottom of the code:

1. Connecting to the websocket server
2. Sending FadeCandy data packets

The first part is easy:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7890');

        socket.onclose = function(event) {
           console.log('Not connected to fcserver');
        }
        socket.onopen = function(event) {
            console.log('Connected');
        }
```

The data part is slightly tricker, but not by much. The full websocket FadeCandy packet specifications are available [here](https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy/blob/master/doc/fc_protocol_websocket.md), however you can look at the `writeFrame()` function within the html examples to see how pixels are sampled, then packed and sent. The [version used in the ganzfeld example](https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy/blob/master/examples/html/ganzfeld.html#L77) is simpler since it sends one colour to all pixels. It might be simpler to start there, then progress to changing individual pixels.

Regarding Java, FadeCandy has a simple protocol built on top of TCP called [OPC (Open Pixel Control)](https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy/blob/master/doc/fc_protocol_opc.md). The simplest way to start may be using the [Processing examples](https://github.com/scanlime/fadecandy/tree/master/examples/processing) (in your case strip64_dot, strip64_flames, strip64_unmapped will help  lot)

**Update**
Here is a basic code sample sending the first 64 pixels from the webcam to FadeCandy:

```js
var webcam;
var fadeCandy;
//how many LEDs are on the strip
var leds = 64;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(390, 240);
  //setup cam
  webcam = createCapture(VIDEO);
  //hide capture html element
  webcam.hide();
  //setup FC
  // Connect to a Fadecandy server running on the same computer, on the default port
  fadeCandy = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7890');
  fadeCandy.onclose = onFCClose();
  fadeCandy.onopen = onFCOpen();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  image(webcam, 0, 0, 320, 240);
  writeFrame();
}
function onFCOpen(event){
  console.log("FadeCandy connected!");
  console.log(event);
}
function onFCClose(event){
  console.log("FadeCandy disconnected!");
  console.log(event);
}

//write frame to FadeCandy
function writeFrame() {
 var packet = new Uint8ClampedArray(4 + leds * 3);

 if (fadeCandy.readyState != WebSocket.OPEN) {
  // The server connection isn't open. Nothing to do.
  return;
 }

 if (fadeCandy.bufferedAmount > packet.length) {
  // The network is lagging, and we still haven't sent the previous frame.
  // Don't flood the network, it will just make us laggy.
  // If fcserver is running on the same computer, it should always be able
  // to keep up with the frames we send, so we shouldn't reach this point.
  return;
 }

//  // Dest position in our packet. Start right after the header.
 var dest = 4;

  //sample pixels
 webcam.loadPixels();
 /*
     sample pixels for each led
     i = counter for the led
     j = counter for pixel
     the j counter is incremented by 4 -> 4 channels (red,green,blue,alpha)
 */
 for(var i = 0,j = 0; i < leds; i++,j+= 4){
   packet[dest++] = webcam.pixels[j];
   packet[dest++] = webcam.pixels[j+1];
   packet[dest++] = webcam.pixels[j+2];
 }
 
 fadeCandy.send(packet.buffer);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.23/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.23/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

You may want to sample pixels differently, but this should give you an idea of how to:

1. Connect to FadeCandy via WebSockets
2. Send FadeCandy pixel data